# comando para poder comparar entre un string y un integer en Python (como condición)

Tags: python

Tengo una duda, ¿como puedo comparar entre string e integer en Python? Quiero que si mi dato ingresado es un string, me de un mensaje y si es un int que continúe mi código.

Código que he probado:

```
n=raw_input("ingrese numero jugadores: ") if str==str(int): 
print("escribe un numero, no una letra")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If str == str(int):
```

En resumen, casteas a string el entero

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar la función `raw_input`, con ella comprobar si lo que se ha introducido es un entero y de ahí continuar con tu idea.

```
while True:
n=raw_input("ingrese numero jugadores: ") 
   try: 
     n=int(n)
     return n

   except ValueError:

      print "Escribe un numero, no una letra."
```

Otra opción es comprobar directamente el tipo:

```
if type(n) !=int:
    raise TypeError, "Escriba un numero"
```

Comment: n=raw_input("ingrese numero jugadores:  ")
if str==str(int):
    print("escribe un numero, no una letra")

Comment: Esto es parte de tu código?

Comment: muchas gracias, me funciono altiro

Answer (score 1):

Tu pregunta es un poco ambigua, pero creo que lo que estas intentando es comparar si una cadena es la representación de un número entero, si es así, lo que se puede hacer es esto:

```
def is_int(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return False


if not is_int('hola'):
    print('Es una cadena de caracteres no un entero')

if not is_int('14'):
    print('Es una cadena de caracteres no un entero')
```

Answer (score 1):

Según lo que entendí a tu pregunta, tengo dos interpretaciones

Suponiendo que los datos ingresados sean un string(desde un input por ejemplo)... y quieras comprobar si contienen enteros, podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
entrada=input(">>")
if not entrada.isdigit():
    print("Por favor usa solo números enteros")
else:
    entero=int(entrada)
    #Continuar la ejecución del código
```

En el caso de que te refieras a una variable y quieras comprobar su tipo:

```
entrada="15" # un string
if type(entrada)==str:
    print("no admito strings")
elif type(entrada)==int:
    #operaciones con el entero
    #Continuar con la ejecución del código
```

En el caso del último no aceptará datos como el "15", pero el primer ejemplo si lo haría.

Espero haber ayudado.

Comment: igual, me queda una duda, en mi caso, ocupo Python 2.7, entonces necesito ocupar raw_input para poder ejecutar mi programa, y el type de raw_input me da str siempre... como lo podría hacer en ese caso?

Comment: Así es también el input de python3. Si el caso es ese te recomiendo usar isdigit().